# Elixir map dig functionality like Ruby Hash#Dig

Tags: elixir

Is there an Elixir equivalent for [Hash#Dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) in Ruby ?

Ruby dig example

```
h = { foo: {bar: {baz: 1}}}

h.dig(:foo, :bar, :baz)           #=> 1
h.dig(:foo, :zot)                 #=> nil
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [`Kernel.get_in/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.html#get_in/2):

```
iex(1)> m = %{foo: %{bar: %{baz: 1}}}
%{foo: %{bar: %{baz: 1}}}
iex(2)> get_in m, [:foo, :bar, :baz]
1
iex(3)> get_in m, [:foo, :zot]
nil
```

Answer (score 2):

`get_in` works fine with maps. To make something that works with both maps and structs, you have to make it yourself:

```
def dig(nil, _), do: nil
def dig(struct, []), do: struct
def dig(struct, [head | tail]) do
  struct
  |> Map.get(head)
  |> dig(tail)
end


> m = %{foo: %{bar: %{baz: 1}}}
> dig m, [:foo, :bar, :baz]
1
> dig m, [:foo, :zot]
nil
> dig m, [:foo, :zot, :qux]
nil
```

Answer (score 1):

Although @Dogbert answer is correct, it will NOT work with structs as [they do not implement the Access behavior by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39855905/326984). However I needed a quick and easy way to access a deeply nested state structure of one of my GenServers in one of my test cases (yeah, I know). The module below did the trick for me:

#### dig.exs

```
defmodule Dig do
  def dig(data, [key | keys]) when is_map(data) do
    dig(Map.get(data, key), keys)
  end

  def dig(data, [key | keys]) when is_list(data) do
    dig(Enum.at(data, key), keys)
  end

  def dig(data, []) do
    data
  end
end
```

#### Usage

```
import Dig    

some_pid
|> :sys.get_state()
|> dig([:nested, :structure, 0, :some, :value])
```