# get_in for nested list & struct in elixir

Tags: elixir

I have a structure

```
s = [
  a: %Bla{
   b: "c"
  }
]
```

I want to take `c` value from it. I'm trying to do

```
get_in(s, [:a, :b])
```

But it's not designed to take value from the struct. Is there any analogue which allows me to fetch `c` from the list with nested struct?

Comment: `get_in(s, [:a, :b]) #=> "c"` for me.

Comment: Crap! Let me investigate why it doesn't work on my side

Comment: @Dogbert updated the question. Struct matters!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As [documented](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html#content), `get_in` does not work with structs by default:

> The Access syntax (foo[bar]) cannot be used to access fields in structs, since structs do not implement the Access behaviour by default. It is also design decision: the dynamic access lookup is meant to be used for dynamic key-value structures, like maps and keywords, and not by static ones like structs.

There are two ways to achieve what you want:

1. Implement `Access` behaviour for your struct.
2. Use `Access.key(:foo)` instead of `:foo`.

I would use (2):

```
iex(1)> defmodule Bla do
...(1)>   defstruct [:b]
...(1)> end
iex(2)> s = [a: %Bla{b: "c"}]
[a: %Bla{b: "c"}]
iex(3)> get_in(s, [:a, Access.key(:b)])
"c"
```

Comment: `Access.key(:foo)` means that if you use `get_in(nil, [Access.key(:foo)])` it will throw a BadMapError rather than returning `nil` :(

Answer (score 4):

Here is my version of `try` function to return values from both maps and structs:

```
def try(map, keys) do
  Enum.reduce(keys, map, fn key, acc -> 
    if acc, do: Map.get(acc, key) 
  end)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my response which is more forgiving of non-map values encountered, such as a mid-traversal value being nil a string or something else `Map.get()` will complain about

This is essentially a more-forgiving version of `Kernel.get_in/2`.  If any key is missing, or if mid-traversal it gets a non-mappy thing, it will return nil.

```
    @spec key_getter(map(), list(atom() | String.t())) :: any() | nil
    def key_getter(nil, _), do: nil
    def key_getter(map_or_struct, []), do: map_or_struct
    def key_getter(map_or_struct, _) when not is_map(map_or_struct), do: nil

    def key_getter(map_or_struct, [next_key | keys]),
      do: key_getter(Map.get(map_or_struct, next_key, nil), keys)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about [Access.key/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html#key/2) not working with non-maps, it's fairly simple to write your own implementation that doesn't throw a fit if the data isn't a map.

```rb
def key(key) do
  # example only includes :get, not :get_and_update
  fn
    :get, %{^key => value}, next -> next.(value)
    :get, _data, next -> next.(nil)
  end
end
```